# Can someone explain this grounding phenomenon?

Tags: grounding, three-phase, conductivity

I went into a conversation with an electrical engineer. Here is what was on the table:

**Me:** How do you connect a two-phase load to a three-phase delta load? If the loads were Y-connected, then you would just take one line wire and the neutral point and connect them to the load. But in the case of a delta source connection, where there is no neutral point, how will you do it?

**Engineer:** You connect the other terminal of the load to the ground.

**Me:** How does this work?

**Engineer:** Three copper rods are inserted vertically into the ground at with specific spacing between them. [Material] is placed at the ends of the rods touching the ground, i.e. between the rods and the ground to increase conductivity. These three rods are connected to one wire - the earth or neutral wire.

**Me:** Why does this work? As far as I know, soil does not conduct electricity that well.

**Engineer:** Deep down into the ground, the conductivity of soil is much better, so the soil at the tips of the copper rods does conduct electricity.

**Me:** Consider the circuit on the left. The lamp lights, doesn't it? What if I connect the same circuit as shown on the right? Does the lamp still light?

[image]

**Engineer:** No.

---

Can someone explain to me the final "no"? Why does the underground soil conduct electricity underground, but **when the same soil is brought up to the surface it fails to do so?**

Comment: \$R=\rho\frac{A}{l}\$. For soil, \$\rho\$ is not so great but \$A\$ is very large. Make your tube of soil a few meters in diameter and it will conduct reasonably.

Comment: why would you connect a two phase load to neutral?  if the tube was 2m diameter and 1cm long would the lamp light?,  see also "SPER" and "High-leg delta"

Comment: Send your "engineer" back to school. Grounding the mid-point of your 2-phase load when supplied from a 3-phase delta supply achieves nothing whatsoever. The soil conductivity is entirely irrelevant since there's no neutral back at the 3-phase delta supply to conduct to.

Comment: @brhans it is assumed that the power supply's neutral wire is also grounded.

Comment: @WaisKamal - I suggest that you remind your "engineer" that a 3-phase *DELTA* supply has no neutral wire.

Answer (score 2):

Damp soil is a rather poor conductor of electricity.  But the Earth has a rather large cross-sectional area to make up for it.  The rock particles are pretty much an insulator, but any water in the soil is bound to have some dissolved salts in it.

A tube of soil is likely to be a vey poor conductor, especially if the soil is dry.

Answer (score 1):

> But in the case of a delta source connection, where there is no neutral point, how will you do it?

A much better answer than the one given would be to use a three-phase delta-wye transformer. The primaries are wired in a delta configuration. The secondaries are wired in a Y configuration. The center-point of the Y is grounded as before, and also connected to the neutral wire of the load.

> Why does the underground soil conduct electricity underground, but when the same soil is brought up to the surface it fails to do so?

A tube of soil contains much less soil than is electrically used by two conducting rods driven into the earth. When resistances are connected in parallel, their total equivalent resistance is *less than* any of the individual resistances. When there are many of these resistances, (all of the same order of magnitude) the total resistance will be *much less than* any of the individual resistances. That is the case when two conductive rods are driven into the ground. Imagine there is one tube which is straight connecting the rods. But another above it, another below it, another to the left, another to the right, another to the right of that, and yet another to the right of that, etc. etc.. In short, the single tube of earth in your example will have a very much higher resistance than the two rods driven into the ground, because you have eliminated so many of the parallel pathways that current could flow. The two situations are significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

I have had bad experience with a ground rod.  I drove a six foot copper pipe into clay soil to ground an antenna and then used an ohmmeter to find its resistance to the house ground system which was connected to the power company and a ground rod at the box. The box was about 60 feet from the antenna.  I was surprised to measure 40 ohms. This happened twice.  As a result I would never use the ground instead of a power return wire.  Not only would I expect to loose power but I would expect the ground rod to be damaged by corrosion.
If the delta power source and system had no ground connection at all I would expect your 3 phase circuit to act like it was open.
The light connected to the tube would likely be dim.